# How to update data in all user redis session

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-session

We use Spring session with Redis, and store in the session user ID and user Role.

When we need to change the user role, we don't want to delete all user session, as the user will need to sing in in all devices.

Is there a way to update the role in all the sessions?